# JDBC and MySQL Statement and ResultSet error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to run the following code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
ResultSet rs = null;
System.out.print("Username: ");
String username = input.next();
System.out.print("\nPassword: ");
String pword = input.next();
String stmt = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '"+username+"' AND password = '"+pword+"' ";
Statement s = con.createStatement();      // con = Connection object
rs = s.executeQuery(stmt);
if(rs.absolute(1)) {
    System.out.println("LOGIN SUCCESSFUL");
}
else {
    System.out.println("INVALID LOGIN");
}
```

However, I end up with the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed for a result set of type ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.absolute(ResultSetImpl.java:391)
    at practice.JDBCtester.login(JDBCtester.java:36)
    at practice.JDBCtester.main(JDBCtester.java:17)
```

Could someone explain the problem with my code?

Comment: Please do not concatenate values into a query string, it makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection. Secondly, please use a proper password hashing algorithm instead of storing plaintext passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `absolute()` you can just verify at least one row was returned. For example you can do:

```
rs = s.executeQuery(stmt);
if (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println("LOGIN SUCCESSFUL");
}
else {
  System.out.println("INVALID LOGIN");
}
```

`absolute()` is an advanced method useful for reading, re-reading, and updating special types of result sets. Your result set is a simple one.

Comment: Much appreciation for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As documented in the [`ResultSet.absolute(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#absolute(int)):

> Throws:
>   `SQLException` - if a database access error occurs; this method is called on a closed result set or the result set type is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`

In most situations, the default result set type is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, so the `absolute` method is not supported.

Instead use `ResultSet.next()` to check if there is at least one row.

As I also commented, your current code is highly insecure. Don't concatenate values into a query string (especially not values obtained from a user), as this makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection. Instead use a prepared statement with parameter placeholders. Also don't store plaintext passwords, but use an appropriate password hashing algorithm.